# In-Place file editing

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm currently trying to implement a little function that reads from a file, does something with the content and should replace it in-place. The text that is read from the file and written to the file is always identical in size. Due to system limitations I have to do everything in-place.
So I've written a little test-example. It writes "abcdefghijklmnop" 16 times, closes the file, opens it again, reads it 16byte-wise and should turn it into upper-case (here: simple char - 32). This is just a minimal example of my problem and I won't use `buf[b] = buf[b] - 32;` in a real-life scenario to upper some characters, so please no comments about this line ;)

At first I tried to use two different `ifstream` and `ofstream` but that did not work: It just edited something at the end of the file and scrabled some data.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char buf[8];
  std::ofstream testdata("testdata");
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    testdata.write("abcdefghijklmnop", 16);
  }
  testdata.close();
  std::ifstream in("testdata");
  std::ofstream out("testdata", std::ofstream::app);
  out.seekp(0, std::ofstream::beg);
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    in.read(buf, 16);
    for(int b = 0; b < 16; ++b) {
      buf[b] = buf[b] - 32;
    }
    out.write(buf, 16);
  }
  in.close();
  out.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Next I tried to use a single `fstream` with some manual seeking.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char buf[8];
  std::ofstream testdata("testdata");
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    testdata.write("abcdefghijklmnop", 16);
  }
  testdata.close();
  std::fstream stream("testdata", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
  stream.seekp(0,std::fstream::beg);
  stream.seekg(0,std::fstream::beg);
  auto inpos = stream.tellg();
  auto outpos = stream.tellp();
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    stream.seekg(inpos);
    stream.read(buf, 16);
    inpos = stream.tellg(); // also tried inpos += 16;
    for(int b = 0; b < 16; ++b) {
      buf[b] = buf[b] - 32;
    }
    stream.seekp(outpos);
    stream.write(buf, 16);
    outpos = stream.tellp(); // also tried outpos += 16;
  }
  stream.close();
  return 0;
}
```

This edits the first 8 bytes, scambles the next 4 and leaves the rest untouched.

What am I missing? Or am I completely off track?

Comment: Are you trying to read 16 bytes into an 8-byte array (`char buf[8]`)?

Comment: @kMaster oh heck, this was the problem... thanks for pointing out. I'm going to sit in a corner now. This was embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments by @kMaster, the second Version works just fine. The only issue was an ill-sized buffer (8 instead of 16 bytes).